# Can't open log file using PHP

Tags: php, file, logging

I'm trying to open a log file **located on my local machine** from my web application hosted on websitepanel, but I keep getting this error message:

> Warning: file(file:///C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\HostingSpaces\ssd19aaron\testproject.tureckidesign.com\wwwroot\application\models\logsmodel.php on line 91

This is the code:

```
$filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log';

$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Why won't the file open when I visit the site?

Comment: Because there is no `C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log` on your host?

Comment: @Daan - right sorry, I edited my question to make it more clear. I'm trying to open a file located on my local machine.

Comment: Where is "websitepanel" hosted? Is it also on your local machine?

Comment: No WebsitePanel is an Arvixe hosting service I'm using for my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer provided by the Arvixe hosting service does not have the same file system as your local computer. You can't give it a file path for one computer and expect a program running on a different computer to find it. That is like trying to navigate Berlin using a map of Paris.

Generally speaking, to get a file from an HTTP client to an HTTP server you will use a form with a file input.

```
<form action="http://Arvixe-hosting-service/example.php" 
      method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Log file <input type="file" name="log"> </label>
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

You can then read the file from

```
$_FILES['log']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to get the file from C:/. Host your file on a logs folder inside your web application and edit the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) like this:

```
$filename = 'logs/access.log';
```

Comment: Emmanouilid - sorry Athanasios, I edited my question to make it more clear. I'm trying to open a file located on my local machine from my web app.

Comment: You need to put that file on your htdocs folder on your local server so it can be accessible to the world. What web server are you using ?

Comment: I'm using WebsitePanel

Comment: I asked what web server you are using on your local machine.

Comment: locally I'm using WAMP

Comment: You should put the files that you want to be accessible to the internet inside the c:\wamp\www folder. Then you can access those files from your application by using the following url http://your.ip.address.here.com/the-file-that-you-want.php . Also be sure you have port 80 open in your firewall/router.